# Что я делаю не так? События Java-Script

Tags: javascript, html, события

Есть код

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function setColor(id) {
      id.style.background-color = black;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="fist" onclick="setColor(this)">text</div>

</body>

</html>
```

В консоли разработчика Firefox событие возвращает:

```
ReferenceError: setColor is not defined
```

Собственно сабж...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так работает

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html lang = "ru">

<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setColor(id) {
            id.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id = "Div1" onclick = "setColor( this );">text</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Или вместо

```
id.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
```

вы можете написать

```
id.style["background-color"] = "Red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Поспешил с вопросом. Проблема в

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setColor(id) {
      id.style.background-color = black;
    }
  </script>
```

Нужно было

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function setColor(id)
{
 id.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
</script>
```

Пардоньте...

Answer (score 0):

```
function setColor(id) {
  id.style.background = 'black';
}
```